# Unable to install drake 1.14 on Mac

Tags: pip, drake

I'm on my Mac, trying to change which install of Drake I'm running for consistency with my team.

From my project folder, when I try to re-install the requirements package:

```
project_folder$ venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get:

> ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python
> version: 2022.1.24 Requires-Python <3.8,>=3.6; 2022.1.3
> Requires-Python <3.8,>=3.6; 2022.1.3b0 Requires-Python <3.8,>=3.6
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> drake>=1.13.0 (from underactuated) (from versions: 1.10.0, 1.11.0,
> 1.12.0)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for drake>=1.13.0

- I've updated pip, and I'm running python 3.10.11.
- I've been sure to use the correct pip and python by specifying `venv/bin/pip` or `venv/bin/python3.10` when trying to run.

What could I do to try to get pip to see the newer versions of Drake?

Comment: The first error message ("Requires-Python <3.8,>=3.6") seems pretty self-explaining?

Comment: You could try (NOTE: I did not!) `brew install python@3.7`  (3.7 conforms to: "<3.8 and >=3.6")

Answer (score 0):

You can see the detailed list of wheel files at this link: https://pypi.org/project/drake/1.14.0/#files

Note that for macOS, there are only Python 3.11 wheels provided, not Python 3.10.  That's why trying to install Drake 1.14 for Python 3.10 is not working. This is consistent with the recent [release notes](https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/v1.13.0.html) where Drake >= v1.13.0 wheels on macOS only support Homebrew Python 3.11.

One solution would be to install and use Python 3.11 from Homebrew. This would be the simplest fix.

Another solution would be to rebuild pydrake yourself [from source](https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html#building-the-python-bindings):

```
git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
cd drake
git checkout v1.15.0
mkdir ../drake-build
cd ../drake-build
cmake ../drake -DPython_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/your/venv/bin/python3.10
make install
```

Note that only Drake >= 1.15 supports selecting a custom Python version, so unfortunately you can't build 1.14 from source this way. Also note that when building from source that SNOPT, MOSEK, and GUROBI will be off by default.